# How to generate reports in selenium webdriver (java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, report

I have written my automation scripts for a registration scenario using selenium webdriver and java in Eclipse IDE creating maven project.

I have written my entire script (End to end application flow) under java main .Now business people are planning to integrate with Jenkins.Can you please help me how to generate reports to see my output results in eclipse and jenkins?

Note :I have not used any cucumber annotations,features files,step definitions,test runner classes.I right click my project in Eclipse IDE and run as java application and see the results in console.

Answer (score 0):

There are several known and widely used tools for creating test reports.
I prefer using [extent report](https://www.extentreports.com/) report.
It can be easily integrated with major testing frameworks like JUnit, NUnit, TestNG, etc.
You can simply find a lot of perfect tutorials how to use it. Like [this](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/extent-reports-in-selenium) and many others.

Comment: As given in the link , I have downloaded extent reports jar file and added jar files to build path. How to add extent reports class?What contents to be put up inside it?Do I need to change my code written under java main?I am confused ...please help

Comment: I have added my code in the given link https://pastebin.com/8JaRLkqC.Please help

Comment: I have to see all your project files to answer this question. Also, this possibly will require several structural changes, so it's not something I can answer simply here.

Comment: What information do you need to further assist me ? @Prophet

Comment: As I see this issue, to set proper reporting in the project is really complex issue, it's not like 'use this locator instead of that' or `you need to and a wait here`. It's about creating and rebuilding the entire project infrastructure. So, I'm sorry, this is not seems to be possible.

Comment: You should learn tutorials, see the best practices other engineers used in their projects. I did that exactly yesterday with my friend. It took as about 2 hours debugging on real project with open IDE. While we both have several years of experience building automation infrastructures. let's say we have in common more than 10 years in this..

Comment: I had 3 years break from industry and now i am back to work.So I just created java class and written my scripts and ran as java application though i created maven project.I dont know how to relate feature files step def and test runner for my application.I am getting error while running cucumber feature file.I couldnt write step def.Any guide to build from scratch in detail @Prophet

Answer (score 0):

Since Selenium does not have itself a reporting functionality we have to import Reporting libraries such as extent reports. It can be easily integrated with major testing frameworks like JUnit, NUnit, TestNG, have .html reports and the level of customisation it offers is commendable. You can read this article.  [here](https://manulwick.medium.com/how-to-use-extent-reports-with-testng-in-selenium-java-c892cf256737)

Also you can use TestNG reports [here](https://manulwick.medium.com/getting-started-with-testng-2bf64521a12c)
But its more advantageable  if you use extent reports